# datatables placeholder not allowing fa icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, icons

I have a standard datatables table setup using this code

```
  <table id="example" class="table dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>UserGroup</th>
                  <th>Join Date</th>
                  <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

Now that all works fine, it displays fine, however when i init my datatables with javascript i can't seem to get HTML of the placeholder for the search filter to display

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "info": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "dom":' <"search"f><"top"l>rt<"bottom"p><"clear">',
                language: {
        search: "_INPUT_"
    },


        });
                $('div.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', '<i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search...');


    });
</script>
```

This all works however instead of the placeholder of the search filter being an icon and saying Search... it just shows the html of  instead of rendering it as an actual icon?

Thanks.

Comment: try this `$('div.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', '&#xf002;');$('div.dataTables_filter input').css('font-family', 'Arial, FontAwesome');`

Comment: Unfortunate that didn't work.